# How to print a PDF to the printer in Qt5

Tags: pdf, printing, qt5

In Qt5 have been introduced the feature to print a `QWebEnginePage` to a PDF file. The question is how to print the PDF that was generated by `QWebEnginePage` to the defaulter (physical) printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for something close is coming in Qt 5.8: http://blog.elangroup-software.com/2016/11/new-print-option-for-qtwebengine-in-qt.html?m=1 It goes directly from the WebEngine to the printer without an intermediate PDF rendering.